# Removing the CSS color for focus state to current color

Tags: html, css

I have some `anchor` tags that get dynamic color based upon the classes assigned to them but on focus, they get a white color cause of `bootstrap overrides`.

now I need to override the default bootstrap style for anchor only with this class say `a.custom-label` and another generic class to get the **original color (before focus)** on focus like this:

```
a.custom-label:focus {
    color: unset;
    color: initial;
    color: revert;
    color: inherit;
    color: none;
}
```

I tried these but nothing seems to work, can someone share a way to achieve this?

Comment: share full code

Comment: try `a.custom-label:focus { color: inherit !important; }` although looking at bootstrap 4, it doesn't change the focus of anchors, just form-controls

Comment: @Pete I tried that but it gives the original color i.e `black` but my `a.custom-label` can get any color purple, green and so on.. I'm using bootstrap 3

Comment: but if you change the colour of the custom label, it will inherit it - can you make a [bootply](https://www.bootply.com/new) showing an example of these non changing coloured links

Comment: @Pete as stated in my question they get color based upon the classes assigned to them like `.custom-label` can have any class like `.custom-label-1` or `.custom-label-2` and so on..

Comment: then you just need to include the focus states when you define them: https://www.bootply.com/7XqUeixY2m (what's so hard about that?)

Comment: @Pete as they were a lot so I was trying to avoid them and wanted to put a style for all of them that will cancel the onfocus color. I will do it that way then

Comment: Don't think you would be able to do that with bootstrap 3, as it has a specific focus style, you need to override it for every focus that needs a different colour - that's the problem with using frameworks, you often get a lot of bloat when overriding styles you don't like (probably why it was removed from 4!)

Comment: @Pete I understand, Thansk for the help I will do it with the traditional way then.

Comment: If you are just wanting a responsive column framework (and want to do your own styling for everything else) I would recommend gridle rather than bootstrap: http://gridle.org/demo/demo.html.  But if you like all the easy things  that boostrap offers like styled forms, collapsible navs, etc, then I would just put up with overriding certain styles

Comment: @Pete Thanks for sharing that, I will definitely look into that but for now, we have an extensive use of bootstrap in this application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best possible way was to remove the default bootstrap label class from my HTML elements and pick all the styles in bootstrap for `.label` class and paste it in my custom.css with a selector `.custom-label` **except on focus styling** like this:

```
.custom-label {
    display: inline;
    padding: .2em .6em .3em;
    font-size: 75%;
    font-weight: 700;
    line-height: 1;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
    white-space: nowrap;
    vertical-align: baseline;
    border-radius: .25em;
}
```

and using only this class for all my elements.

this gives all the default style of bootstrap but as no styling for `onfocus` was pasted so issue got fixed.

Answer (score 0):

```
a.custom-label:focus { color: #000 !important; }
```

You can change color you want in place of #000. Also if you don't want to use !important then add external css and call it below bootstrap css in head block.

Comment: I need the color before focus and it can be any color.

Comment: Please create fiddle or pen so i can get more clarity.

Comment: @ZeeshanAdil so define the color of *before focus*

Comment: Do one thing than, Remove code from bootstrap css which is used for focus color white. You can find exact location of file and line number for code in inspect element.

Comment: @TemaniAfif this gets color dynamically based upon other classes assigned to them

Answer (score 0):

Try putting "!important" after the color name 
for examle:

```
a.custom-label:focus {
    color: #2d2d2d !important; }
```